# BusyBox Ubuntu Issue

Tags: dual-boot, busybox

This is quite wierd. So my friend dmed me about his system not booting and showed me that BusyBox shows up instead of Windows 10. Now he wanted to dualboot Windows 10 and Ubuntu so I went to his house and installed Ubuntu and Windows 10. He ended up not liking it because of his drive space being too small for all his files that he needed. He backed up the files and wiped all his drives and installed Windows 10. Everything went good so far until today, his pc only boots in BusyBox and he can't even enter BIOS or Boot Menu. He has a MSi Trident X 10th Gen. Anybody who knows what to do in this case?

Comment: When you install a second OS on a machine; it usually takes ownership of the boot process as it allows you to select your prior OS & the new OS (where if the boot process as owned/controlled by the first OS it won't know about the other OS). It sounds like you forget to make the first OS (windows) take ownership of the boot process; which is now broken as it's trying to boot a *removed* (thus not there) OS & resulting in `busybox`.  Your recovery media for your first OS will correct this issue (which is windows as you describe it).

Comment: Well it worked for about 3 days. It could be that a partition was not wiped correctly and something happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your description of the steps you've taken is inconsistent with the result you are seeing which sounds like an initramfs prompt. Windows doesn't use busybox or initramfs, so if you are seeing that, then you did not wipe all of the drives as you claim.

If you want to use Ubuntu to wipe your hard drives, you can boot the Ubuntu installation media from a USB and choose "Try Ubuntu".  Then you can open the "Disks" application to format each hard drive. This will effectively erase everything on those drives.

Simply choose the disk on the left and choose "Format" from the drop down. Since you are planning to install Windows, choose "GPT" as the partition scheme when it asks.

If you do this for all hard drives, it will not be possible for any remnants from Ubuntu to remain.  You will have a blank slate.

As far as installing Windows, that is off-topic and if you continue to have Windows installation issues, you can ask about that on SuperUser.

Your issues accessing BIOS are unrelated to any operating system so it has nothing to do with Ubuntu. BIOS is your motherboard's firmware.  Generally you need to press a key immediately after power-on to access BIOS settings.  Usually vendors will notify you which key to press on the splash. In case that is disabled or you are unsure, read the documentation for your computer's motherboard. All motherboards are different.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Ill do some troubleshooting with the motherboard since when Fast Boot there is no splash screen. I asked the MSi forum about it and if CMOS is removed it resets that option then it should work.

Comment: It's usually ESC, DEL or an F- key. Often F1, F2, F4 or F12